Calculate Total Continuous Date Range
I'm pretty new to SAS and I have a dataset with a lot of overlapping date ranges for different ID numbers.
Essentially I'm trying to find out if any particular ID had a total continuous date range of 180 days at the same location without any gaps of a day or more.
Example Dataset:



Id
Location
Start Date
End Date




001
Texas
1/1/2020
1/30/2020


001
Texas
1/5/2020
1/6/2020


001
Texas
1/8/2020
1/10/2020


001
Texas
1/13/2020
2/20/2020


001
Texas
1/21/2020
1/29/2020


001
Texas
1/21/2020
2/5/2020


001
New York
2/15/2020
3/15/2020


002
Maine
1/1/2020
3/30/2020


002
Maine
1/10/2020
1/20/2020


002
Maine
1/15/2020
1/18/2020


002
Maine
3/20/2020
7/20/2020


002
Kansas
7/10/2020
9/30/2020



In the example data, you can see that ID 002 had > 180 continuous days in Maine from 1/1 - 7/20 which is what I'd be trying to catch.
I started by trying using a lag function to get the previous row's end date compared to the current row's start date and check if there was a gap of more than a day. The problem is that, like in rows 2 and 3 of the example, the query would flag as a gap from 1/6/2020 to 1/8/2020 even though that gap was covered by the 1/1/2020 - 1/30/2020 in the first row.
Then I tried setting up an iterative version of this where it checks if Prev End Date > End Date and if so, it updates the Adj End Date to be the Prev End Date (example below):



Row
Id
Location
Start Date
End Date
Prev End Date
Adj End Date




1
001
Texas
1/1/2020
1/30/2020




2
001
Texas
1/5/2020
1/6/2020
1/30/2020
1/30/2020


3
001
Texas
1/8/2020
1/10/2020
1/6/2020
1/10/2020


4
001
Texas
1/13/2020
2/20/2020
1/10/2020
2/20/2020


5
001
Texas
1/21/2020
1/29/2020
2/20/2020
2/20/2020


6
001
Texas
1/21/2020
2/1/2020
1/29/2020
2/1/2020


7
001
New York
2/15/2020
3/15/2020
2/1/2020
1/29/2020


8
002
Maine
1/1/2020
3/30/2020
1/29/2020
3/30/2020


9
002
Maine
1/10/2020
1/20/2020
3/30/2020
3/30/2020


10
002
Maine
1/15/2020
1/18/2020
1/20/2020
1/20/2020


11
002
Maine
3/20/2020
7/20/2020
1/20/2020
7/20/2020


12
002
Kansas
7/10/2020
9/30/2020
7/20/2020
9/30/2020



The problem is that this only works for one row. So row 2 catches that there was an overlap and sets the Adj End Date to 1/30/2020 which is great, but the overlap from row 1 also covers row 3 and isn't caught so row 3's Adj End Date is before row 2's.
Based on this, I tried to write a data step that would iterate through the dataset and continually update the Adj End Date based on the previous row but this is where my minimal understanding of SAS failed me.
The query:
data have;
     set have;
     if ID = lag1(ID) and End Date <= lag1(End Date) then Adj End Date = lag1(End Date);
run;

What I expected was that every row would continually update with the 1st row's End Date (in this example dataset) until reaching row 5 where the End Date was no longer greater than the previous row's End Date. What actually happened was that it would fix the first row (row 2 in this case) after an overlap, but then stop working on subsequent rows.
Based on this, I tried using a do while loop to iterate over each row multiple times but I just can't seem to get it to work this way. It just seems to still only work once per overlap instance even if several row's dates are overlapped.
I hope this makes sense. I'm just so out of depth with SAS and running out of time to figure this out. Any help or guidance would be so appreciated!

This topic has been covered several times in prior questions. [Group cross date range in SAS], [Finding the total duration of multiple overlapping "start date" and "end date" entries]  In general, novel solutions can be created by leveraging the fact that a SAS date value is a reasonable integer that can be used as an array index.
